# Booklet from PDF - Available. PDF from Booklet Example Is Needed

Tags: java, pdfbox

I came across a beautiful project called [PrintDF](https://github.com/Raudius/PrintDF) which uses Apache PDF box library to convert a PDF **to** a booklet PDF.

Now can someone help me with the inverse - meaning an example to create a PDF **from** a booklet PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not want to download, built and start the project. What does it do? Resize a PDF? It would be helpful if you would provide and example input and output document.

Comment: What exactly do you want? (some example input/output, clearer definition of "booklet PDF" -- is it even a format?)what library are you using, your existing code -- if any) Isn't that a PDF already?

Comment: This library create booklets from PDF. This library converts A4 PDF to booklet. What i want is the reverse. Booklet -> To A4 PDF. The java file - https://github.com/Raudius/PrintDF/blob/master/src/us/raudi/printdf/PrintDF.java does the A4 to Booklet PDF conversion on clicking Create Booklet Button after running the project/program. My option is the reverse.